# Splitting expression with String#split()

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I want to convert a infix operation to postfix operation. My code works when the input is given as already split expression through an array. But it doesn't when the input is given as the raw String expression.

```
String[] exp={"23","+","32"}//this works
String str="23 + 32";
String[]exp=str.split("//s+" );//this doesn't work
```

Comment: Whats `//st`? Are you sure you don't mean `\\s`?

Comment: This is usually done with stacks. Are you sure that you want to use arrays?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue in the end? If so, don't forget to upvote any answers that helped and click the grey tick to accept the answer which help you most.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use backslash instead of slash:

```
String[] exp = str.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: yes...   earlier it was a mistake. but it doesn't work now either. Don't we get a same array as String[] exp={"23","+","32"} when split the string expression with whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

You had 2 issues I could see in your code. The first is that your second `String[]` has the same variable name as your first. The second is that you were using forward-slashes instead of back-slashes.

```
    String[] exp = {"23","+","32"};
    String str = "23 + 32";
    String[] exp2 = str.split("\\s+"); // or " +"

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exp));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exp2));
```

The above is working correctly for me.

I hope this helps.